# How do i export text from illustrator to photoshop with editable text and layer style?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, export, layer-style

(At first sorry for my english)
I was working on text using illustrator cc which have one fill with gradient and a stroke.

For more editing i export it in cs6 for firework which can help me with more editing option for photoshop, then i saved it as psd mode but when i open it in as photoshop psd file it became raster with no editable independent.

My actual question is it possible to save text with all layer style from illustrator and then edit in photoshop as text with all style ? i also tried direct exporting from illustrator to photoshop! But it's not working.  [image][image]

Comment: Many times I too face this problem.. I googled it searched it a lot, but did not find any way to export from AI to PS with actual editable layers. I don't think any possible way. May be Adobe admins do this in further updated version of AI & PS

Comment: Why exactly do you need to edit your Illustrator content within Photoshop? If you place your Illustrator file as a Smart Object in Photoshop, you can still edit it (in Illustrator, but via Photoshop) while also being able to apply Photoshop effects to it. Is there something specific you need to do that this does not cover?

Answer (score 1):

This process of exporting your design to Photoshop  with layers in tact is pretty straight forward, however the real issue is your not being able to export from Illustrator to Photoshop. You're problem stems from routing your file through Fireworks.

In Illustrator, from the "File" menu select "Export". A "save" window will appear and select "Photoshop .psd" from the "Format" dropdown button below the file name.

An options dialog will appear [image: that looks like this]

If you slect the buttons as shown in the linked image, you'll have no problem editing text or shapes in Photoshop.

You mentioned not being able to export to Photoshop from Illustrator. To resolve this I would contact Adobe Tech Support.

Answer (score -3):

You can't. Welcome to the wonderful Adobe world ;)